# influxdb-client-python in multiprocessing: TypeError("cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object")

Tags: python, influxdb

I'm running a multiprocessing.Pool and am downloading data via the influxdb-client-python.

The code boils down to:

```py
def do_stuff():
    InfluxDBClient(
        url=os.environ["INFLUX_HOST"],
        token=os.environ["INFLUX_TOKEN"],
        org=os.environ["INFLUX_ORGANIZATION"],
    ).query_api().query_raw(
        f"""
            from(bucket: "foo")
            |> range(start: 2023-11-07T00:00:00+00:00, stop: 2023-11-08T00:00:00+00:00)
        """
    )

with multiprocessing.get_context("spawn").Pool() as pool:
    pool.map(
        do_stuff,
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        chunksize=1,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the error thrown by influxdb causes the problem. There was an issue with the token, and instead of ending up in the console somewhere, it somehow turns into

```
multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '<multiprocessing.pool.ExceptionWithTraceback object at 0x7fa7be9dbd10>'. Reason: 'TypeError("cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object")'
```

Essentially, I just wrapped the `query_raw` call into a try catch block to log the error properly.